# Textbox uses previous AutoCompleteCustomSource's suggestions when source is changed

Tags: vb.net

I've been searching around for a solution to this problem to no avail.  I've got a small VB.net program that allows the user to change the autocomplete source file for the textboxes on the form.  If there's no autocomplete file selected on load, the program makes you select one.

If a new file is selected when there's already an autocomplete file, then the textboxes will use suggestions from both until the program is restarted, where it'll start only using the newly selected file.  Is there any way to prevent this behaviour?

Here's the code for selecting the file:

```
Dim fd As OpenFileDialog = New OpenFileDialog()

        fd.Title = "Select a file..."
        fd.InitialDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments)
        fd.Filter = "Text files (*.txt)|*.txt"
        fd.RestoreDirectory = True

        If fd.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
            My.Settings.streamerFileLocation = fd.FileName

            Call Form1_Load(Me, e)

            stream1Textbox.Text = ""
            stream2Textbox.Text = ""
            stream3Textbox.Text = ""
            stream4Textbox.Text = ""
        End If
```

And the releveannt part of the Form1_Load sub that it calls:

```
Using reader As New System.IO.StreamReader(My.Settings.streamerFileLocation)
            While Not reader.EndOfStream
                autocompleteList.Add(reader.ReadLine())
            End While
        End Using

        stream1Textbox.AutoCompleteCustomSource = autocompleteList
        stream2Textbox.AutoCompleteCustomSource = autocompleteList
        stream3Textbox.AutoCompleteCustomSource = autocompleteList
        stream4Textbox.AutoCompleteCustomSource = autocompleteList
```

Comment: Yes. Code something to do that. You need to save that selection from the user and then on load, use that information to load it instead of asking or not loading or whatever you do now. It's like asking a textbox to hold the value typed by a user for the next time your app runs. It will only do that if you code it to do that.

Comment: But it does do that - My.Settings.streamerFileLocation has permanence and is the variable that gets updated when you select a new file.  The issue is, if I start the program connected to a file with "Cat" in it, and then select another file with "Dog" in it, the program will still auto-complete the word "Cat".  The only way to get auto-complete results from ONLY the new file is to restart the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A friend helped me figure it out - the program was still hanging on to the old entries between file changes for whatever reason.  Added in **autocompleteList.Clear()** before the While loop:

```
Using reader As New System.IO.StreamReader(My.Settings.streamerFileLocation)
            autocompleteList.Clear() // THIS LINE 
            While Not reader.EndOfStream
                autocompleteList.Add(reader.ReadLine())
            End While
        End Using
```

And hey presto, no more old auto-complete suggestions.